# Переполнение положительных и отрицательных чисел не используя max_value

Tags: ассемблер, проверка, переполнение

Объяснили, что регистр ax может содержать числа от 0 до 65535, но при добалении туда отрицательных то от -32768 до +32767. Однако всё же, как проверить переполнение положительных и отрицательных чисел через jo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот что происходит с флагами переноса, знака, переполнения при получении результата сложения и вычитания в нескольких диапазонах:

```
 mov ax, 2000h  //  ax        CF  SF  OF 
 mov dx, 4000h  //            0   0   0
 add ax, dx     // 6000h      0   0   0
 add ax, dx     // A000h      0   1   1 
 add ax, dx     // E000h      0   1   0
 add ax, dx     // 2000h      1   0   0 
 sub ax, dx     // E000h      1   1   0
 sub ax, dx     // A000h      0   1   0
 sub ax, dx     // 6000h      0   0   1
 sub ax, dx     // 2000h      0   0   0
```

Остаётся проанализировать и проверять соответствующие флаги